# SSIS- Cannot Create user component - Component Entry Point Attribute

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, script-component

I created a Data flow task, with a simple flow inside.

The script component type is destination.

[image]

First I look for some data from my database, then I transform it, and finally insert it to my CRM database.

I'am using Microsoft.Xrm sdks.

Here is the error I'm getting
[image]

Reading the error, it says that I have to make sure there is one class marked with `SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute`

I confirm that the scriptMain class is already marked
[image]

For information, even is the script component is blank, I mean as is when created , without my code, it stills giving the same error.

And I don't have any build or analysis error

Comment: If you've added any custom code to the class, copy it out. Then delete the Script Component and re-add it. Open the new script component and then close the script editor session. That will set the initial class "stuff" so we can identify whether the error was in the initialization of the autogenerated classes or something you may have done afterwards.

Comment: @billinkc I did that many times, with same result. Wich means that the problem is from the initialization?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was be inclined to believe. Perhaps a reinstall of the SSIS project is in order because this stuff should just "work". Behind the scenes, VS uses the [vstax files](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/slimming-down-ssis-script-task.html) as the starting template to make the classes but I've not seen instances where they were corrupted or anything. VSTA1?_IS_CS_Template.vstax with location dependent on VS versions, etc

Comment: the reinstall didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Anything unusual about your setup? Outside of the data flow, can you create a Script Task? Curious whether it's something specific to Script items or just the Component. Have you built any packages previously that use a Script Component? Based on the error message, translator software says that's likely a French/French adjacent language. I'm not aware of an incompatibility with that localization but I'm a dumb 'merican in these matters.